# IonRouterOulet does not apply page transition in ios. Ionic React

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-router, ionic5, ionic-react

I'm trying to apply default transition that comes out of the box from IonRouterOutlet, and i noticed that it only worked on andriod platform not on ios.

index.ts

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <IonReactRouter>
      <App />
    </IonReactRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.tsx

```
<IonApp>
  <MainTabs />
  <IonRouterOutlet>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
    <Route exact path="/get-started" component={GetStarted} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/myself" component={SignMyself} />
    <Route exact path="/company" component={SignCompany} />
  </IonRouterOutlet>
</IonApp>
```

The transition from one page to another works well on android and does not work at all in ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IonReactRouter` should be a child of the `IonApp` element

```
<IonApp>
  <IonReactRouter>
  <MainTabs />
  <IonRouterOutlet>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
    <Route exact path="/get-started" component={GetStarted} />
    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
    <Route exact path="/myself" component={SignMyself} />
    <Route exact path="/company" component={SignCompany} />
  </IonRouterOutlet>
  </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>
```

Comment: Please can you explain the use case sir

Comment: i dont understand?